# Why do we say Dayanim Mumhim in Hatarat Nedarim (Canceling vows)?

Tags: beit-din-court, rosh-hashanah-new-year, nedarim-shevuot

The text of *Hatatarat Nedarim* starts like this:

> שִׁמְעוּ נָא רַבּותַי דַּיָּנִים **מֻמְחִים**
> "Please hear, expert *Dayanim* (court)

It's not just that usually we gather three random people to be *Dayanim*, who are not necessarily "Experts". We know (Tur YO"D p228) that:

> מי שנדר ...ילך אצל חכם מומחה..., ואם אין יחיד מומחה ילך אצל ג' הדיוטות ... והאידנא אין מומחה שיהא ראוי להתיר ביחיד בפחות מג
>
> One who had taken a vow... will go to an expert sage... and if there is no expert will go at three simple people...and nowadays, we have no experts, that are worthy to cancel a vow alone, with less the three people.

So, if you need three people, they are obviously not "experts", why do we say they are?

Comment: A strong question! I suppose, this phrase in the Machzor was eventually copied with a mistake, the original phrase should read "שמעו נא רבותי דיים, המומחים להתיר", they are surely not דיינים מומחים, but they are מומחים להתיר.

Comment: It's just a nice thing to say.

Comment: @AlBerko Add a source, and it will be an answer

Comment: @Rafael can't we find other nice thing to say, that does not contradict Halach?